# Pygame.display.set_icon unable to show transparecy

Tags: python, pygame, file-format, png

On Python 3.2.5 32 bit, I installed pygame. I made some code with it. It included `pygame.display.set_icon(image)`. The image file is .png and I loaded it by using `image = pygame.image.load("clockico.png").convert_alpha()` The transparent pixels on the .png file showed up as black. I tried using a `.ico` file instead of a `.png` file, but the output was the same. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `convert_alpha()` part to just `convert()`, as the `convert_alpha()` changes the transparent pixels.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, using Pygame 1.9.6, I have found that all I need to do is to scale my PNG image to match an allowed Windows icon size. For example, with my 80x80 image, I do:

```
icon = pygame.image.load(ICON_FILENAME)
icon = pygame.transform.smoothscale(icon, (96, 96))
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
```

If you're only using the image as an icon (and not planning to reuse the image object), you do not need to call `image.convert()` or `image.convert_alpha()`. In fact, I would recommend setting your icon as early as possible, even before you call `pygame.display.set_mode()`, and `convert()` or `convert_alpha()` will fail if you call them that early.